# How to manage multiple url with OrientGraphFactory

Tags: orientdb

I configured a OrientDB Cluster with 3 nodes.
Suppose that the node names are:

- leonardo.domain.ext
- michelangelo.domain.ext
- donatello.domain.ext

I have a configuration file to get this urls and create the proper url to pass to OrientGraphFactory (e.g. remote:leonardo.domain.ext/mydb)

I create the GraphFactory as following:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(url,username,password).setupPool(1, 10);
```

If leonardo is down when I try to create OrientGraphFactory I don't have any issues, but I get an Exception when I do.

```
factory.getNoTx();
```

Reading the documentation https://orientdb.gitbooks.io/orientdb-manual/content/orientdb.wiki/Distributed-Architecture-Lifecycle.html I understand that if leonardo go down (for any reason) the clients automatically reconnect to the other instances.
This is valid for the factory and the connection that it will try to create in the future or just for the active ones?

Do I have to manage to recreate the Factory in my application ?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? It worked?

Answer (score 2):

You could use all those addresses separated by a semicolon:

`remote:leonardo.domain.ext;michelangelo.domain.ext;donatello.domain.ext/mydb`

OrientDB will try connecting to the first, but if it's unreachable, it will try the others in sequence.

It will also do load balancing at client side, if you are on 2.2.x version.

Hope it helps.